# Spring Boot with Spring Social Google provider

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social, spring-social-google

Any example how to integrate Spring Boot application with Spring Social Google ([GabiAxel/spring-social-google](https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google)) provider? I found this [project](https://github.com/callistaenterprise/blog-social-login-with-spring-social), but it seems to be unfinished. Spring Boot explains how to get it working with Spring Facebook, Twitter, but is it the same for log in with Google?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-boot) is exactly what I need, but extended with Google provider

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned in your question, you can use that project hosted on github.

You can use this [dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-google/1.0.0.RELEASE)

In a Configuration class, you will have to extend SocialConfigurerAdapter, override the addConnectionFactories method and add GoogleConnectionFactory. For example :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig extends SocialConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer, Environment environment) {
    GoogleConnectionFactory googleConnectionFactory = new GoogleConnectionFactory(environment.getProperty("spring.social.google.app-id"), environment.getProperty("spring.social.google.app-secret"));
    googleConnectionFactory.setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
    connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(googleConnectionFactory);
}
@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public Google google(ConnectionRepository repository) {
    Connection<Google> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(Google.class);
    return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
}
}
```

You can use this along with the Spring Social examples.

Comment: this very similar to what I have already. I have still only /connect mapping auto-added, shouldn't I have also some /signin mappings added by Spring Boot to be able to log in?